# WCF service hosting using website other than "Default Web Site", default port, net.tcp

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

My basic question is for guidance hosting a WCF service in IIS7 (2008 R2) on the default net.tcp port of 808 on a website other than "Default Web Site".  I have 4 sites each bound to a specific IP address.  I would like my WCF services to be hosted within a site other than the default using port 808.  What is the catch here?  I want to understand this without just using another port to solve the issue if that would even be the case.

I created this running question/log of trying to figure this out yesterday, but I just didn't have much luck.  I had to move the WCF services back to the default website and move the net.tcp binding from my desired website back to the default as well.

[moved net.tcp WCF services from localhost to IP address on new site, services won't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422413/solved-o-o-moved-net-tcp-wcf-services-from-localhost-to-ip-address-on-new-site)

I access my services using the technique of:

```
MyServiceClient : ClientBase<IMyService>, IMyDataService
```

and within the methods of the client:

```
return base.Channel.MyOperation(request);
```

I rely on the WCF configs in web.config of the hosting projects providing the .svc file to properly connect me to the WCF services.  If this is sub-optimal, I am willing to change.

A typical client configuration in web.config looks as such:

```
<endpoint name="myServiceClient" address="net.tcp://localhost/MyServiceWebHost/MyService.svc/tcpEndpoint"  binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myServiceNetTcpBinding"  contract="Contracts.ServiceContracts.IMyService" />
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Its rights issue. Right click on your new website --> then Edit Permissions. On properties window click security tab and Edit button. Then Add IIS_IUSRS and give Read & execute, List folder contents, Read permissions. Now you can host and connect net tcp on new website.